# On AJAX Post: New Form is submitting before all other GET is completed

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a single form that searches by keyword. The form does an ajax request to another page and prints the results into the success function.

For example it's searching movie titles. So if I type in 'Nightmare on Elm Street' AJAX POST to the other page, page recieves the GET and does a `$('#status').html(response);`

Each result is a form with Movie Title and a 'Go' input button so the user can say 'Yeah this is the movie I want'.

It starts to populate the response just fine then all of a sudden the results start to submit random forms of the response before it is finished.

Here is the code to get 'Movie Title' keyword and populate results.

```
<?php
   $myid = strtoupper($_REQUEST['thetitle']);

   $titles = $tmdb_V3->searchMovie($myid,'en');

   foreach($titles['results'] as $result) {

   ?>
   <form name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['id']); ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="mid" id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['id']); ?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['id']); ?>" />
         Title: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['title']); ?>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Go"></div>
   </form>
<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("form").submit(function() {
           var id = $(this).children('input[type="hidden"]').attr('value');
           $.ajax({
           async: false,
               type: "POST",
               url: "sx.php",
               data:"mid="+ id,
               cache: false,
             timeout: 30000,
               success: function(data){
   $('#status').html(data);
               }
           });
          return false;
      });
   });

</script>
```

Like I said, the results start to populate the #results div then all of a sudden will submit the 'New' POST request before finishing the results.

Its a 3 step function sort of say: "Search => Results => Get Movie Info"

Results are 'Unknown' I don't know the array of results, I don't think I can use .when

Here is a screen shot of firebug:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/IUbHRdw.jpg]

How can I stop the new forms from submitting until the first ajax request is complete and the user actually clicks on the new submit button?

Comment: What's actually that w500 request? Also, note that you are probably including script nodes when populating #status, so maybe you can rather do something like `$('#status').html($(response).filter(':not(script)'))`

Comment: The w500 request is calling for an image of 500px width, I have replacement functions for that, it's not an issue. As you can see the 2nd form sx.php is being called before those errors anyways. The script is submitting to sx.php without an actual click for some reason... that's my issue.

Comment: I'm asking because a 4xx or 5xx might trigger some other strange behaviour. Whenever I'm baffled by an error like this, I first try to make sure all side conditions are ok, so I can rule out those are part of the problem.

Comment: Thought I solved it but turns out after 50+ trys its still submitting ;/

Comment: have you tried evt.preventDefault?

Comment: yes I have, no luck...